# How to disable VSCode notebook cell output path autodetect

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

In VSCodes default notebook rendering, there seems to run some sort of path autodetect that turns any text that starts with a '/' into a link. I am feeling a bit stupid but I can't find a way to disable that. Any ideas?

This is what I mean

[image: 1]

I expected to find a setting that disable the path detection. I couldn't find a way so far even after intensive search

Comment: Related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/12975

Answer (score 1):

This will be supported in the January 2024 release of VS Code (1.86) by setting `notebook.output.linkifyFilePaths` to `false`. If you can't wait, use VS Code Insiders.

See [Disable filepath highlighting
#181922](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/181922).